# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs & Images Intercepting the Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic HTML page which has Twitter Bootstrap, I am using the Tabs element which works to a point however I have images wrapped in a tags which denote the different tabs, when a tab is clicked the image intercepts the click and navigates the user to an "undefined" page hoever clicking around the image activates the tabs as normal.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="margin-left: 0px;">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fr" > <img src="img/flags/fr.png" alt="Françaises" title="Françaises" width="16" height="16" align="middle" style="margin-top: -4px;" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to stop this without setting the image as a background in CSS?

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you recreate the problem on jsfiddle.net or link to your page?

Comment: Ok solved it I have had to use a background image after all will post the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Solved with css

CSS:

```
.frFlag {background-size: 16px 16px;background-image: url(img/flags/nl.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;}
```

html

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fr" style=" class="frFlag">&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
```

Thanks for the time stackers!

Comment: Good solution. For me the css was going to be too tricky so I manually switch tabs with js and find parent node if the image is clicked.